# Issue with generating excel sheets in a web application

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc

While working in a web application I have some issues with generating the excel sheet based on the result. This excel sheet data should be independent for each request. As of now I have implemented in the following way:

Created a xml file for excel configuration

```
spring-excel-views.xml
<bean id="excelView" class="com.test.service.excelService"

I have configure this xml in the servlet configuration file
<bean class="xmlReolver> //Mentioned clearly in the code but not here
  <property name="location>
     <value>bin/spring-excel-views.xml</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Now I have controller class as well as an Utility class
UtiilityClass: computes the results and send back to the Controller

```
Controller: model.addAttribute("result", result); //Assuming result  is  coming for Utility class
```

Now in excelService.java coded as follows:

```
class ExcelService implements AbstractExcelView{



 @overridden
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map model,HttpServletRequest req, HTTPServletResponse res){
    Map m = model.getResults("results"); // Picking this from Controller
    for(Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry: m.entrySet()){ -->Exception is throwing
//excel sheet logiic
}
    //iteration logic  ----> Exception thrown here
    }
    }
```

Here sometimes excel sheet is generating successfully and sometimes it is throwing **Nullpointerexception** before starting the iteration. Also this excel data is overriding with some other requests data. Displayed result is good but I'm having the problem with the excel sheet data.

Help me out to resolve this issue.

**Exception Stack trace**

```
Exception  Report:
type Exception report
message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
description: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.
org. springframework. web. servlet. FrameworkServlet . processRequest (FrarneworkServlet. java: 932)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(Frameworkservlet.java:816)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java: 620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service (FrameworkServlet.java:801)
javax.servlet.http.Httpservlet.service(Httpservlet.java:727)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
com. hello. services.ExcelService.buildExcelDocument (Excelservice.java:34)
org. springframework.web.servlet.view.document.AbstractExcelView.renderMergedoutputModel (AbstractE
org.springfranework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render (AbstractView.java:264)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render (Dispatcherservlet.java: 1208)
org. springframework . web . serviet . DispatcherServlet . processDispatchResult (DispatcherServlet . java: 1208
org. springframework. web. servlet . DispatcherServlet . doDispatch (DispatcherServlet . java: 939)
org. springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService (DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org. springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest (FrameworkServlet.java: 920)
org. springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet (FrameeworkServlet.java:816)
javax.servlet.http.Httpservlet.service(Httpservlet.java: 620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service (FraneworkServlet.java:801)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Httpservlet.java:727)
```

Comment: Getting the correct data to the controller and displaying it in the view correctly. The only problem with generating the excel  sheets

Comment: could you put the iteration logic where you are getting the error also pasting the stacktrace of the error would be really helpful.

Comment: @SarfarazKhan: Updated the exception as per your  suggestion. While entering the for loop its throwing exception. I feel like once I click on excel button its unable to find the exact thread. That's why it is throwing exception. Can you suggest how I have to generate the excel report for each request independently

Comment: Am able to get the results to jsp page correctly as per the request. But am unable to generate the excel sheet properly.

Comment: what are you using to generate the excel file? Is it a library like apache.poi or some custom code? My first impression is you've probably got an autoboxing issue that's throwing the null pointer exception in ExcelService.java line 34. (ie you set some primitive value equal to a null-instantiated version of its wrapper-class like int = null Integer)

Comment: @encrest am using apache poi..The problem is in browsers like chrome its working fine. in IE throwingthis exception. Evenin chrome it throws 3 out 10 attempts. And if I send multiple requests results were bit messy. I mean reports of 1 request adding  to to the other request

Comment: @PoojaL would it be possible for you to post some code from Excelservice.java specially some around 34 line no.

Comment: @SarfarazKhan: Map<String,String> results = (Map<String,String>) model.get("results");
  //create a wordsheet
  HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(" Report");
 
  HSSFRow header = sheet.createRow(0);
  header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Month");
  header.createCell(1).setCellValue("Revenue");
 
  int rowNum = 1;
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : revenueData.entrySet()) {
   //create the row data
   HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
   row.createCell(0).setCellValue(entry.getKey());
   row.createCell(1).setCellValue(entry.getValue());
                }

Comment: @SarfarazKhan: Do you think this ExcelService code does work in multi threaded env? Because I am not sure about  this

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out that exception is throwing in the below line

> for(Map.Entry entry: m.entrySet()){ -->Exception is throwing

You are getting this exception because model.getResults("results") is returning null.Thus your **m** is assigned null and doing m.entrySet() this on null reference is throwing null pointer exception.

So you'll have to figure out why model.getResults("results") is returning null and fix it. If there can occur situation where there will be no excel sheet generated and model.getResults("results") will return nulll. Then you'll have to provide appropriate checking in your code.Below is a checking but it may not be sufficient as you may to handle some more stuffs.

```
if(m!=null){
  for(Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry: m.entrySet()){ -->Exception is throwing
    //excel sheet logiic
  }
  //iteration logic  ----> Exception thrown here
}
```

Regarding you question about Thread safe it completely depends how you have designed your class and using it which is very difficult to answer just by looking at the few lines. However this may not be an issue of Thread safe.